# Selecting elements great grand children by jquery and changing its width

Tags: javascript

I need to select an element `<th>A</th>` in a table whose path is `*[@id="something"]/table/thead/tr/th[2]` and change its width.

```js
(function ITPscript() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#something table thead tr:nth-child(2)").width(1000);
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="something" class="aaa">
  <table class="sortable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>0</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>G</th>
        <th>H</th>
        <th>I</th>
        <th>J</th>
        <th>K</th>
        <th>L</th>
        <th>M</th>
        <th>N</th>
        <th>O</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="aBody">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

I'm using `$("#something table thead tr:nth-child(2)").width(140);` but its not working. Need a proper way to select the element.

Answer (score 0):

`:nth-child` does not select *the nth child* of the element, it selects the element which ***is** the nth child of its parent.* The selector needs to be `... tr th:nth-child(2)`:

```js
(function ITPscript() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#something table thead tr th:nth-child(2)").width(1000);
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="something" class="aaa">
  <table class="sortable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>0</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>G</th>
        <th>H</th>
        <th>I</th>
        <th>J</th>
        <th>K</th>
        <th>L</th>
        <th>M</th>
        <th>N</th>
        <th>O</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="aBody">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have used nth child in the body tab with tr to select the elements. $("#iaBody tr").each(function() {var tid=$(':nth-child(5)',this).

Comment: Your "but" doesn't change how `:nth-child` is defined: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child In a context where there's no qualifying selector attached to it, `:nth-child` selects *any* element which is the *nth* child. I.e. it's like `tr :nth-child()` (`tr *:nth-child`); which is not the same as `tr:nth-child()`.

Comment: but there was <td>, worked in main code thanks but i'm still confused lol